# Feature branching using git subrepos

Tags: git, git-subrepo

I have a project which is using git subrepo: https://github.com/ingydotnet/git-subrepo and I'm trying to figure out how to implement feature branching as a dev workflow.

Here is what I have so far:

1. Create a branch in the monorepo
2. Make your changes in the monorepo
3. Make a pull request for your branch into master
4. After the pull request is merged into master, run `git subrepo push --all` to also push the commits to their respective repos

Does this sound right? At no point have I had to use `git subrepo branch` or `git subrepo commit` so I feel like this workflow isn't actually the intended workflow for feature branching with git subrepos. If the workflow I've suggested is correct, what is the actual purpose of the subrepo branching and committing commands?

Comment: Any reason you chose to create a sub-repo instead of a [branch](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging)?

Comment: I have this same question and your four steps seems like the intended workflow.   However, I *think* that if your FB workflow is to stay in the original repo, you would have to create the FB on the original branch and reclone.  I believe `git subrepo branch/commit` are lower-level commands that are normally done automatically for you.